# Cursor pointer show only on header text on center of the header not full header to show the pointer

Tags: css

I am trying to show cursor pointer only on header text not full header.
I hade tried with given - text-center but its have issue of pointer showing on where mouse over on header but my requirement show pointer only on text on the header

Mycode like this

```
  <div id="header-container">
    <p class="text-center">Header Text</p>
  </div>
```

Please help me out

Comment: post some code...

Comment: Normally you need to post code here (and you probably still do), but wrapping your text in a `<span>` element and moving the `cursor: pointer;` to the span might fix this.

Comment: @JonUleis This site is about coding, so one should _always_ post some code, and it is only in very rare cases that does not apply and this one is not one of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the actual text in an inline element, such as a span, and styling it's hover state:

```
<header>
    <span>your text here</span>
</header>


header span:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan Gee -- issue fixed